# Circular background for a div content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of items using flex box i need to get a circular highlight around the dynamic content which are numbers in this case shown by

`{galleyCartsDet\[0\].quantity}`

`{galleyCartsDet\[1\].quantity}`  etc is there a `css` approach for this

```
<div className='galley-carts'>
        <div class='flexCol floatRight'>
            <ul>
              <span><b>Galley Details</b></span> <br/>
              <li className='floatRight'>{galleyCartsDet[0].quantity} Full Cart</li><br/>
              <li className='floatRight'>{galleyCartsDet[1].quantity} Half Cart</li><br/>
              <li className='floatRight'>{galleyCartsDet[2].quantity} SMU</li><br/>
              <li className='floatRight'>{galleyCartsDet[3].quantity} Stowage</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

i have tried

```
.carts_circle{
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background: yellow; 
  }
```

but doesn't seems to work

```
<div className='galley-carts'>
        <div class='flexCol floatRight'>
            <ul>
              <span><b>Galley Details</b></span> <br/>
<li className='floatRight'><div classname="cart_circle">{galleyCartsDet[0].quantity}</div> Full Cart</li><br/>
              <li className='floatRight'><div classname="cart_circle">{galleyCartsDet[1].quantity}</div> Half Cart</li><br/>
              <li className='floatRight'><div classname="cart_circle">{galleyCartsDet[2].quantity}</div> SMU</li><br/>
              <li className='floatRight'><div classname="cart_circle">{galleyCartsDet[3].quantity}</div> Stowage</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You can't have an element between the `ul` and `li`. Anyhow, you're best off showing just the relevant HTML and CSS, in a usable demo. Do you just want a number with a circle around it?

Comment: Are you using some sort of preprocessor because what you have shown isn’t HTML. Please tag whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you forgot the **"s"** in your class name inside the html. And I am not sure why you use "ClassName" instead of "class"? Also don't use a "break" `</br>` at the end of a li element.

To display a circle in front of the li content and to center the number inside this circle, you should add:

```
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

So the html part should look like:

```
<li class='floatRight'><div class="carts_circle">{galleyCartsDet[0].quantity}</div> Full Cart</li>
```

And the css for it:

```
.carts_circle{
      border-radius: 50%; /* better to use 50% */
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background: yellow;
      display:inline-flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}
```